# AngularJS multi page app auth with Spring Security

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building my first AngularJS app with Spring Auth and Spring Rest services. I have built and tested the CRUD pages. Now I am trying to implement auth using Spring Security. I have some success in implementing the login login, but I have multiple problems and need your help in resolving the same.

Below is what I have till now

**spring security.xml**

```
<http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="restUnauthorizedEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/html/login.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/s/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <form-login login-page="/html/login.html" 
        username-parameter="ssoId" password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="true" invalidate-session="true" 
        logout-success-url="/html/login.html"/>

    <csrf token-repository-ref="tokenRepository" />
</http>
```

**Login page controller**

```
app.controller("login", function($scope, $http, $log) {
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        $log.debug($scope.login);
        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "../login",
        data : "ssoId="+$scope.login.ssoId+"&password="+$scope.login.password,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "X-Login-Ajax-call": 'true'
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            //location.href="./dashboard.html";
            $log.debug("success : " + angular.toJson(response));
        }, function(response) {
            $log.debug("error : " + angular.toJson(response));
        });
    }
})
```

**RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint**

```
@Component
public class RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

I have below issues

1. I am not getting response HTTP status 401 even when I am using bad creds
   and returning `HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED` from
   `RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint`
2. How to get user information from Spring app and store it across pages in my angular js app, specially because it's a multi page app.
3. Is there any tutorial I can follow for multi page angularjs app authentication with Spring Security? All tutorials I found are for AngularJS SPA which is not my situation.

Comment: For (3), no tutorial, but my [open source blogging tool](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog) is a multi-page Angular JS app using Spring Security throughout: login, roles, etc.  It probably can demonstrate what you're asking for in (2) as well.